# in which file request blocking iis rules get added in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I have added some request blocking rules in URL rewrite of IIS. Then I checked for these rules in web.config and in app config file. I did not find. In which file these changes are made?

Comment: i don.t think you will see the blocking rules will written to your web.config or app.config because these files are used to instruct the IIS and not vice versa. Going by this link: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template i believe that your rules might be under the inetpub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules get added in folder level web.config file